# WCF client service communication

Tags: wcf, stack, channel, transport

I have a very basic question about wcf service with basicHttpbinding:
When client calls a wcf service(basichttpbinding) synchronously how the request and response is received between two? Does a socket connection established between 2 and port on server tied up till response is received on client? How the response is sent back to the waiting client? IF port on server is unusable for long running operation then will it hinder service ability to accept request from other client? Also, how communication happens in can of asynchronous call to wcf service? I read that channel and hence port/socket should remain open at both ends.

Answer (score 0):

With basichttpbinding, it's much the same as normal http communication between a browser and a web server. If you hit a link on a web page, a request from the browser is sent to the appropriate web server, which processes the request and returns the content, as a response, to the waiting browser.

It's the same with WCF basicHTTPBinding. The WCF client sends a post or get request to the designated web service (http: //webservice:port/ServiceObj/MethodName) and waits for a response. When the web service finishes gathering the data, the data is sent back to the client in the response on the open connection, which is then closed by the host. There's no persistant connection. Thus, basichttpbinding is stateless. Once the web service sends the response, connection is recycled and the service is ready to go for the next request.

If the client is finished with its communication, it can close its connection explicitly; that's best. But if it doesn't close its connection, it won't make any difference to the host.

Comment: Thanks, I have still one query, when you say connection is recycled what exactly it means. If its web service port 80 is used at server to listen for the request. If there are multiple clients sending request to the service and each client has connection with the servers till response is received, are we eating connection on server side? Connection is simply a combination of client ip and port and server ip and port .On server side port and ip are same, all clients are connected to same ip and port combination on server. So what connections I am recycling?

Comment: Recycling was probably the wrong word since is implies re-use. From my understanding, the connections are closed on the server side after the response is sent back to the client. WCF hosts can run many, many concurrent connections on the host side. If too many requests come in at a given time, requests are automatically queued by WCF and processed when the system has a chance.